# Reading Mails from Outlook Javamail

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, imap

Am trying to read the emails from the outlook using javamail

herez the code snippet.

```
try {
      Properties props = new Properties();        
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");    
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "outlook.office365.com");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "143");    
      Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props); 
      mailSession.setDebug(true);
      Store mailStore = mailSession.getStore("imaps");
      mailStore.connect("outlook.office365.com", "<username>", "<password>");                     
  } catch (Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

***Exception***

javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:727)

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Port 143 is the plaintext port, it will not work for SSL.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very confused.  Keep it simple:

```
  Properties props = new Properties();        
  props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");     
  Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props); 
  mailSession.setDebug(true);
  Store mailStore = mailSession.getStore("imap");
  mailStore.connect("outlook.office365.com", "<username>", "<password>");
```

Use the "imap" protocol, but tell JavaMail to enable SSL.  Don't worry about ports, JavaMail knows what to do.  More detail in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#outlook).

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the reply it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Post your comments i verified the code of Session. You are correct. Inside the code it is clearly defined that the default values. We no need to supply.

Answer (score 0):

Port 143 (what you're using) is for plain-text IMAP (hence the error message `plaintext connection?`). IMAPS uses port 993, so try that.